# What is the format of DB Connection URI for connecting Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, prisma

I've been using Heroku Postgres databases for local dev environments. Heroku provides these DB's URI's in a super easy format that contains all the connection info. I use this as an .env variable that Prisma JS connects to. It works great, super easy.

`postgres://<DB_USER>:<DB_PASS>@ec2-3-210-23-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<DB_NAME>`

Now I am switching to trying Google Cloud SQL but they don't provide the same easy to consume connection string. They provide a public IP address, a "connection name" that seems to contain the GCP region, Cloud SQL instance name, etc.

Connection name is a string in this format: `<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>:us-central1:<CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>`

Would anyone know what format I can combine the attributes in to make a ? And what is the host URL for Google Cloud? Should I use the public IP address?

I see a lot of docs on how to do this in the Google Cloud Run env, but if I want to work locally, how can I connect?

Comment: The URI is formatted the way URIs are formatted.  Heroku didn't invent that.  Maybe you should show us what you get from Google, I don't know what a "connection name" is.

Comment: I've updated my post with a connection name example from GCP. `<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>:us-central1:<CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>`

Comment: I agree, I thought the format was standard but in the examples I've been googling I've been seeing other formats.

For example this [GCP Doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors) links out to [this doc on connecting with JDBC](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md) which has this example URI:
`jdbc:postgresql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>`

Comment: But this doc also mentions installing a Gradle Cloud SQL dependency. So I'm not sure what the actual host is if I want to connect with only a JDBC URI and no other dependencies.

Comment: Where are you running your app? What is your Cloud SQL configuration (private IP only? public IP? DB engine type and version?)

Comment: Could you take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4170), the solutions there should also work for you.